# Should I add verses in Kerias Shema on the bed

Tags: tefilla, bircas-krias-shema

When saying the 3 parshiyot of Kerias Shema on the bed, should I add "Kel Melech Ne'eman" before the  Kerias Shema (Since it is read Yechidi (alone) and not in Minyan). Should I say after the verse Shma Israel "Baruch Shem Kvod Malchutu Leolam Vaed"? (According to Minhag Ashkenazim Nusach Sfard)

Comment: Baruch Shem you always say after. And you only say Kel Melech if you say all 3 paragraphs. So in other words if u davened maariv before nightfall, you’ll have to repeat the full shema at night, and you do this on your bed before you sleep, and here you would say Kel Melech. But on a regular night if u already davened maariv after nightfall, you’re only saying the first paragraph of shema before you sleep, so you don’t say Kel Melech